# How to get my inner elements in Linq2Objects?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-objects

I have a simple XML file here which I converted to XSD with xsd.exe and then converted to a strongly typed class with the /C on xsd.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyStruct>
  <Test Name="Test1">
    <Params>
      <Param Name="Param1">I am param1</Param>
      <Param Name="Param2">I am param2</Param>
    </Params>
  </Test>
  <Test Name="Test2">
    <Params>
      <Param Name="Param1">I am param1</Param>
      <Param Name="Param2">I am param2</Param>
    </Params>
  </Test>
</MyStruct>
```

Now I read in the XML like so

```
 myStruct.ReadXml(file, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```

Now I can check the properties off of myStruct and I can see Params and Test. Great!

Now using a simple link query I do this

```
 var tests = from s in myStruct.Test select s;
```

and sure enough I can see Test1 and Test2. Now understand then inside Test1 and Test2 there is Params. I notice I can do

```
 GetParamsRows();
```

and then I can do a foreach over it, each element is ParamsRow. And what is returns I can't seem to see "I am param1" or "I am param2".

Do I need an inner join or something?

I thought picking up a test has a collection or Params inside so i should be able to see it.

### Edit

Now what I do notice is that in Test there is a test_id and in Params there is a Params_id and a Test_id.

It appears the relationship properties are setup but do I have to create the JOINS manual.

### Test

I notice a property called Tables and in there are my 3 tables, I presume I need to do joins on these i.e from test to params to param.  Like a database?

Am I on the right lines?

Comment: It took me a moment to work out a functional code example. I finally realized that you used the /dataset switch instead of the /classes switch. At any rate, a working code example has been added to my response. Cheers!

Comment: no i did use the classes switch /c ---  according to this /c[lasses]
 

Generates classes that correspond to the specified schema. To read XML data into the object, use the System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserializer method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem to be the case that you are actually *not* using LINQ to XML. What you have in this case is an XML-serializable set of classes generated by XSD.exe, and LINQ to Objects queries against those classes. The serializable classes use the older XML classes (`XmlDocument`, `XmlElement`, etc.) instead of the new ones (`XDocument`, `XElement`, etc.).

If you are interested in using pure LINQ to XML, consider checking out the following tutorial, which I think you can adapt quickly to your needs:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing

---

**UPDATE: Non-LINQ-to-XML Solution**

What I believe is the immediate problem you face is that XSD.exe did not infer that you intended the `<Test>` element to contain *at most one* `<Params>` element. It is being treated as though there may be an *array* of `<Params>` elements.

The `ParamsRow` type represents a single `<Params>` element; not the individual `<Param>` elements. I'd wager a pretty rock out of the garden that the `ParamsRow` object has a `GetParamRows()` method (note the singular).

**Another Update**

The example below performs the same operation as the LINQ-to-XML example. It iterates through each test and prints the test along with its parameters. For convenience, I use the `SelectMany()` extension method which "flattens" out the results into a single collection of `ParamRow` objects.

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct();
myStruct.ReadXml(@".\MyXml.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
foreach (MyStruct.TestRow test in myStruct.Test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test #" + test.Name);
    foreach (var param in test.GetParamsRows().SelectMany(ps => ps.GetParamRows()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- {0}: {1}", param.Name, param.Param_Text);
    }
}
```

Check it out and let me know if that settles it.

---

The following LINQ to XML example iterates through each Test element and presents its parameters on the console. Notice that the example does *not* use the classes generated with XSD.exe, and it does not require or employ the schema.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@".\MyXml.xml");
foreach (var test in doc.Descendants("Test"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test #" + test.Attribute("Name").Value);
    foreach (var param in test.Descendants("Param"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "- {0}: {1}",
            param.Attribute("Name").Value,
            param.Value);
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Test #Test1
- Param1: I am param1
- Param2: I am param2
Test #Test2
- Param1: I am param1
- Param2: I am param2
```

Comment: Yes actually i am using LINQ2OBJECTS as i converted my XML (XSD) to strongly typed classes. Sorry i should update the question.